# best practice using method in a class

Tags: class, oop

Suppose I have Employee class, should I put in the Employee class the add, delete, view, etc. methods? or should that class only for the getter/setter class?

which is better/acceptable/best practice?

```
Employee
-------------------
+int id (get/set)
+string name (get/set) (methods are called in another class)

Employee
-------------------
+int id (get/set)
+string name (get/set)
-add employee
-remove employee
```

Comment: You should create two components, and choose one which addresses the problem easily or smoothly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This comes down to [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)

When you are deciding these things, you need to use your intuition and think about it logically. What concerns an employee.

You have a class called `Employee`, then include in the `Employee` class everything that concerns an *Employee*. It doesn't make sense for an employee to be able to `Add` and `Remove` *Employees* to themselves. Maybe what you are looking for there is a class of `Employees` (plural) that will manage your employees ect ect ect.

But your `Employee` "will" have `Name` and `Id` and other things that concern it.

The goal here is to break up your concepts in to concrete real world concerns as much as possible, it makes it much easier to understand a design if you do

Comment: This is the right answer, it doesn't make sense to have Employee to `add` and `remove` employee. If it was something like Employee skills, then you would have `AddSkill()` and `RemoveSkill()` etc.

Comment: OP did not mention, but we can assume a database behind. The question: what implements the Add functionality that inserts the record into the database table?

Comment: @PepitoSh yup good point, i think your answer will cover that. cheers

Comment: yes i am working in a MySql database, i can understand the though that employee class should have method related to it

Comment: another question: i will have Employee class and another class like EmployeeQuery for the add, edit, delete, etc. for database?

Comment: @RandyB. if your are using entity framework, then no, just use it. if you are using standard sqlconnection and commands, probably yes.. however if you are doing higher level stuff with employees, you can make a business logic unit, called employee manager that does employee management stuff

Comment: ok thank you. i am just a beginner, an intern, so i am gathering all the concepts

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a database behind:

For similar purposes I have a base class for all entities that takes care of CRUD functionality and the ID. All entities inherit from this base class and take care of individual properties, like name, address, etc.

Also I have collections of all entities of the same type that manage the items in it.

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: Go with option 2

If you consider the separations of concerns, you should have an **Employee** to track the information of a single person and an **Employee Repository** for managing all of your employees. What makes up an record should be independent from how the record is stored/queried.

Answer (score 0):

Employee class has information of employee, and the methods of employee. Looks like you are trying to maintain a collection of employees (assuming from add, delete employee requirement)

In that case add,delete,remove are not the responsibilities of employee class, rather the collection of employees.

Read on the OOP principles.

Answer (score 0):

First 5 Principles of Object Oriented Design(S.O.L.I.D).

After Employee

```
public class Employee :ViewModelBase, IEditableObject
{
   public int EmployeeID { get; set; }

   public string FullName
  {
     get
     {
         return $"{this.Name} {this.Surname}";
     }
   }

    private string _Name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set
        {
           _Name = value;
           OnPropertyChanged("Name");
         }
     }
}
```

After Create a Generics class with Repository For managment Add,Delete,Update etc...

```
public interface IRepository<T> where TEntity  : class
{
    IEnumerable<TEntity> GetUsers();
    IQueryable<TEntity> SearchFor(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate);
    TEntity GetById(int id);
    void Save(TEntity model);
    void Delete(int id);
}
```

And Employee Base implementation Repository

```
public Class EmployeeManager : Repository<Employee>
{
    public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetUsers()
    {
       //your code
    }
    public IQueryable<TEntity> SearchFor(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
       //your code
    }
    public TEntity GetById(int id)
    {
       //your code
    }
    public void Save(TEntity model)
    {
        //your code
    }
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
        //your code
    }

    public void DeleteAll(Employee[] employees)
    {
       //your code
    }
 }
```

[Unity Repository Best Practices](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/121966/unity-repository-best-practices)

Comment: oh i am just a beginner, i cannot understand this, i coded c# mysql crud but the lead developer wanted me to simplify into classes. i think your solution is too complex in my part :(

Answer (score -2):

I think you should have all the tools you need in one class, have multiple constructors to help load only the info as needed.

Comment: Your statement conflicts with the [Single responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) principle.